# Is there a gettext utility that will allow me to change PO files from the command line by offering a msgid and a new msgstring as an argument?

Tags: linux, command-line, gettext

Is there a gettext utility that will allow me to change PO files from the command line by offering a msgid and a new msgstring as an argument?

Comment: Probably not, but you could easily cobble one together with polib.

Comment: @Ignacio, add this as the answer and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen a complete tool that does this, but it should be easy enough to put one together using [polib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/polib/) to parse and manipulate the file, with a small bit of glue code to parse the command line arguments.